# 2D Peak finding in linear time

Tags: algorithm

I am reading [this O(n) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120300/2d-peak-finding-algorithm-in-on-worst-case-time) of the 2D peak finding problem. The author says that an important detail is to

> split by the maximum direction. For square arrays this means that
>   split directions will be alternating.

Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the longer side ensures that the length of the split is at most sqrt(area).  He could have also gone through the proof noticing that he's halving area with each call and he looks at most 3 sqrt(area) cells to do so.

Comment: But why is it important to ensure that limit on the length of the split?

Comment: You're trying to bound the total length of all splits in the execution of the algorithm.  If a split can be Omega(area) cells long, you get a bound of O(area), rather than O(sqrt(area)).  (That is, O(N^2) instead of O(N).)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a necessary. The alternating direction gives O(N) for any arrays.

Let's count the number of comparisons for an array M × N.

First iteration gives 3×M, second gives 3×N/2, third gives 3×M/4, fourth gives 3×N/8, i.e.:

```
3 * (M + M/4 + M/16 + ...) + 3 * (N/2 + N/8 + N/32 + ...)
```

We got two geometric series. Cause both of these series has common ratio 1/4, we can calculate the upper limit:

```
3 * (4 * M/3 + 2 * N/3)
```

Cause O(const × N) = O(N) and O(M + N) = O(N), we have O(N) algorithm.

If we always choose the vertical direction, then performance of algorithm is O(logM × N). If M much more N, then this algorithm will be faster. F.e. if M = 1025 and N = 3, then count of comparisons in the first algorithm is comparable to 1000, and in the second algorithm is comparable to 30.

Splitting an array by the maximum direction, we got the faster algorithm for specific values of M and N. Is this algorithm O(N)? Yes, cause even comparing both vertical and horizontal sections at each step we have 3 × (M + M/2 + M/4 + ...) + 3 × (N + N/2 + N/4 + ...) = 3 * (2 × M + 2 × N) comparisons, i.e. O(M + N) = O(N). But we always choose only one direction at each step.

Comment: No; you lose the asymptotic bound if you split along the long side.

Comment: @tmyklebu You're right. In square matrix it gives O(N * log N).

Comment: I thought about the question. To linear performance is sufficient to alternate vertical and horizontal iterations. For M*N matrix it gives M + N/2 + M/4 + N/8 + M/16 + N/32 + ... comparisons. Upper limit of the progression is 4/3 * M + 2/3 * N. i.e. it's linear algorithm. However, if at each iteration we choose shortest side, the algorithm will be faster even.

Comment: Edit your answer so that it contains that information and you'll win an upvote.

Comment: Thanks. I'm no so long ago on the site, so I don't know must I edit my wrong answer or not.

Comment: Shouldn't the ratio be 1/2 instead of 1/4 because we're halving number of rows/columns?